# Changing color of a line in plot when certain condition is met

Tags: r, plotly

I have a plot of a probability of an event which changes in time (x-axis is time and y-axis is the probability variable). Beside that in data I have a variable that can have value 0 or 1. What I am looking for is that the probability line has black color when the binary value is 0 and when the binary variable is 1 then the probability line is red. So at the moment I have only the plot of the probability. I don't know how to incorporate the binary variable.

```
plot_ly(df,x=df$time,y=df$probab,type="line")
```

Answer (score 1):

To make things easy I made an example with multiple steps:

```
df <- data.frame(time = 1:11
                 , probab = seq(0.1,0.2, by=0.01)
                 ,bin = rep(1,11))

linecol <- c("black","red")[max(df$bin)+1]

plot_ly(df,x=df$time,y=df$probab,type="scatter", mode="lines"
        , line = list(color=linecol))
```

I assumed the binary value was in the dataframe, but offcourse another source can be used as well.

Your remark on your question makes it a bit more complex. I suggest to divide your line into different sections of lines. This means duplicating the points of the data, to make the sections.

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(time = 1:11
                 , probab = seq(0.1,0.2, by=0.01)
                 ,bin = c(rep(0:1,5),1))


df2 <- df[c(1,rep(2:10,each=2),11),]
df2$section = rep(1:10, each=2)

linecol <- c("black","red")[df2$bin[seq(1,20,by=2)]+1]
linecol <- rep(linecol,each=2)
p <- plot_ly(df2 %>% group_by(section),x=~time,y=~probab)
add_trace(p, mode = "markers+lines",color = linecol)
```

For some reason add_trace did not identify the red and black string as a color. Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Would you mind explaning what do the [] do in "c("black","red")[max(df$bin)+1]"? I'm quite new to R.

Comment: I tried to tweak the example code you gave, I changed bin to c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0). But the line's color stays the same from 0 to 11.Did I misunderstood how your code works?

Comment: My code sets the color for the entire line that will be plotted, hence you can set the color of the line once, Do you mean you want a line that has different colors on different sections? The color will be black if all bin values are 0.
the brackets are to select the color. If the value between brackets is 1 it selects black and 2 it selects red. These are R vector basics. Following a R course or tutorial would help you much.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. And yes, I wanted different colors on different segments, so if at time 1 and 2 the bin is 0 then I want it to be black for example and if the bin for time 3 and 4 is 1 then the color would be red. I would then have a plot where I would have 2 different colors at once. The bin can change several times. I apologize for the misunderstanding.